# Install paru in archlinux docker container

Tags: docker, sudo, archlinux

Some of the programs that I'd like to have in my docker container are some what hard to get on Debian. So I decided to use arch linux and one of the programs that I need is [`x86_64-elf-gcc`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/x86_64-elf-gcc/). since it is on the AUR I'm currently trying to install paru.

Unfortunately dough [`makepkg`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Makepkg) has to be run by a normal user with sudo privileges.
Is there some way I could run it as root?

Or can I create such a user in a docker container and then use some flags so `makepkg` doesn't use `sudo`?

This is what I have done so far:

```
FROM archlinux

RUN pacman -Sy --noconfirm
RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm
RUN pacman -S cmake --noconfirm
RUN pacman -S git --noconfirm
RUN pacman -S base-devel --noconfirm



WORKDIR /tmp
RUN useradd dev -G wheel -d /buildenv -p password
USER dev

RUN git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/paru.git
WORKDIR /tmp/paru

RUN makepkg -si
```

This does not work since `dev` does not have sudo privileges and sudo can't even be run since there is no terminal.

This is the error I get:

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
==> ERROR: 'pacman' failed to install missing dependencies.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the password requirement. For example

```
RUN useradd -m -G wheel -s /bin/bash debug
RUN sed -Ei 's/^#\ (%wheel.*NOPASSWD.*)/\1/' /etc/sudoers
USER debug
WORKDIR /home/debug/
RUN git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/paru.git && cd paru \
  && makepkg -si --noconfirm && cd .. && rm -rf paru
```

Comment: `sed -Ei 's/^#\ (%wheel.*NOPASSWD.*)/\1/'` `/etc/sudoers` is not writable. Also, sed? Just `chmod +w /etc/sudoers && echo 'wheel NOPASSWD....' >> /etc/sudoers && chmod -w /etc/sudoers`

Comment: @KamilCuk it does not matter if /etc/sudoers is not writable, sed will replace it. Obviously this is just an example, if  you don't like sed or would rather use another tool for this change, feel free to do so.